# POST image with some other params with MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, json, post, windows-phone, content-type

I need to POST some data to an API but I am not sure where to put my headers. Here is my code:

```
    private async Task<string> PostTest()
    {
        string boundary = "----CustomBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        string servResp = "";

        strURI = "www.something.."
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Content-Type");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent("application/json"), "Expected-Response-Mime-Type");
            content.Add(new StringContent("en-US"), "language");
            content.Add(new StringContent("blue"), "color");
            content.Add(new StringContent("12/11/15"), "date");

            ImageForm.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
            content.Add(ImageForm, "myPic", MyFileName);

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, strExpenseURL);
            request.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
            request.Content = content;

            httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            servResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return servResp;
    }
```

I want my request content-type to be: "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary

and my response content-type: "application/json"

Are these the right places I am setting these two?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpMultipartFormDataContent multipart = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
multipart.Add(new HttpStringContent("Bob"), "name");
multipart.Add(new HttpStringContent("Hero"), "job", "foo.txt");
multipart.Add(new HttpBufferContent((new byte[] { 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24 }).AsBuffer()), "Thing3");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, multipart);
```

Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);

Read more [here](http://monkeyweekend.com/2014-04-01/httpmultipartformdatacontent-vs-httpmultipartcontent/).

Comment: replace StringContent with HttpStringContent